# Is $k\langle X \rangle \cong k[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $k$ be a field. Is $k\langle X \rangle  \cong k[X]$? Here the left hand side denotes the free algebra generated by $X$, the right hand side are polynomials with coefficients in $X$.

I guess the answer is yes, but I want a quick sanity check.

Comment: I don't know what the univrsal property is. For me the free algebra is just the set of all formal $k$-combinations in $X$ and powers of $X$.

Comment: [This property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object#Definition).

Comment: Is $X$ a set or a single symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, as stated in the comments, is yes. Recall that the free $k$-algebra on a set of generators $X_1,\dots, X_n$ is the free $k$-module with basis consisting of all words in the elements $X_1,\dots, X_n,$ with multiplication given by concatenation of words. For example, if $a,b\in k,$ then $a X_1X_2 X_1 X_3$ and $b X_4X_1 X_2 X_4 X_5$ are both elements of $k\langle X_1,\dots, X_6\rangle$, and their product is
$$
(a X_1X_2 X_1 X_3)(b X_4X_1 X_2 X_4 X_5) = ab X_1 X_2 X_1 X_3 X_4X_1 X_2 X_4 X_5.
$$

However, if $n=1,$ words are simply just some number of $X$'s -- i.e., powers of $X$! So, the free $k$-algebra on a single generator $X$ is the free $k$-module with basis $1, X, XX = X^2, X^3,\dots$, and with multiplication given on basis elements by $(aX^i)(bX^j) = ab X^{i+j}.$ This is precisely the polynomial algebra $k[X]$ in one indeterminate.